# How can $(\ln n)^4 < n$?

Tags: limits, logarithms, asymptotics

I'm reading a paper about [Randomized Rumor Spreading](http://archive.cone.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/pubs/rumor.pdf). The paper uses a push&pull scheme to send messages in a graph. I'm confused about the startup phase: how can there be at least $(\ln n)^4$ informed players if the total number of players is $n$, since the total number of players is smaller than $(\ln n)^4$ when $n$ is large?

Comment: $(\ln(n))^4$ grows more slowly than $n$. Try plugging in $10^{100}$.

Comment: Recall that for any $a$ we have eventually $e^n>n^a$

Comment: Look at the function $f(x)=\ln(x)/x^{1/4}$ for $x\geq 10^5$. We have $f(10^5)<1$ and $f'(x)=\frac{4-\ln(x)}{4x^{5/4}}< 0$ for $x>e^4$.

Comment: Let $x:=\ln{n}$. Then you ask how can $x^4<e^x$. Surely the right hand side grows faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! The result seems obvious to me now. I got confused from plotting the functions and it seeming like (ln(x))^4 grows faster.

Answer (score 1):

According to Geogebra, this can be explained very easily:

[image]

... but zooming out of this, reveals the following graph for larger numbers:

[image]

Comment: You seem to be supporting the OP's argument rather than proving them wrong. Yep, it looks like $(\ln x)^4>x$. Except ... it is not true for $x>5503.66$ approx. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x-%28ln+x%29%5E4+from+0+to+10000

Comment: @StinkingBishop: when I saw your value $5503.66$ I thought you were heavily mistaking, but zooming out clearly proved I was the one messing up :-)

Comment: There are analytical solutions to confirm your results.  (+1)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: thanks. I honestly don't understand those downvotes, is it such a sin to illustrate something?

Comment: Do not try to understand the mystery of anonymous downvotes. Welcome to the club of their victims. Cheers :-)

Comment: The tooltip over the "downvote" button says "*this answer is not useful*". Now, I guess it is a lot more useful that you've shown to the OP how $(\ln x)^4$ eventually trails behind $x$ ... hope this will prompt people to retract downvotes (but I won't hold my breath).